# 503 error on post request from nodejs application

Tags: node.js, http-post

Im Trying to create ticket with attachment using request module of NodeJs. But not able to do so. I get an error: "Exception":"API Gateway encountered an error. Error Message: Native service provider error. Code : 503.

Following is the code used when making the post request.Is there any error in the api call?

```
var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  uri: URL,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'x-Gateway-APIKey': KEY,
    'Authorization': token
  },
  formData: {
    'entry': JSON.stringify({
      "values": {
        "key1" : value1,
        "key2" : value2   
      },
      "options": {
        "contentType": "application/json"
      }
    }),
    'attach-z2AF_Act_Attachment_1': {
      'value': fs.createReadStream(attachment),
      'options': {
        'contentType': 'application/octet-stream'
      }
    }
  }
};
```

The post request works fine through postman.
[image]

Update on the issue:Seems the issue is with

```
'attach-z2AF_Act_Attachment_1': {
      'value': fs.createReadStream('sample.txt'),
      'options': {
        'contentType': 'application/octet-stream'
      }
    }
```

Do I need convert 'sample.txt' to binary format before passing in 'value' ?

Comment: Hello @sree, We cannot know if there's an issue in the API if you don't show us it's code / or mention what it is (If it's not yours). But usually the HTTP 503 code refers to an issue on the server.

Comment: Using postman, it is working but while implementing in code it is showing error.
There must be issue in implementation only. (above code) Also attached a picture of success on postman in the question.Please check